# $.ajax taking time to send huge post data

Tags: jquery, ajax

i am working on route api. In this api, i need to pass huge geocode data in my POST polyline parameter(nearly 1 mb in size).For testing purpose, we added "hello world" in our response file and nothing else.i am getting 10.1 sec as response time.This is due to polyline parameter which is taking 10 sec to send its value(nearly 1 mb in size).I tried with {processData: false} in post call but its not working . Please help me to optimize ajax call so that i can get response in milliseconds.I am getting response in milliseconds for GET request but its taking time(10 sec) with huge POST request data.

```
var data_url ="http://example.com/api.php";
    ajaxArr = $.ajax({
        url:data_url,
        data:{'polyline':'37.779381,-122.418435,37.779381,-122.418435,37.779153,-122.418391....'},
        dataType:"json",
        method:"POST",
        beforeSend: function()
        {
            $("#load_stations").css({'display':'block'});
        },
        success:function(msg){
        }
    });
```

Comment: Did you look at the profiler/network tab in more detail? Is time spent in your client-side JavaScript before the request is sent or in sending the data over or in processing the response, ..?

Comment: Its time spend by ajax to sent api call as response is  just "hello world"  string with no other backend processing.In network tab its showing {Sending: 10 sec}

Comment: So are you sure your backend isn't just very slow at receiving the data?

Comment: What makes you think that processing and sending 10mb should be able to be done in milliseconds?

Comment: There is no problem with backend since i use php curl( with post call) to send the api and it took 2.5 sec.

Comment: So can you show us the cURL call that's fast?

Comment: I am traversing the results meaning 10 sec per api hit * 100 api call = 16 minute which is too slow for website.It will be good if i get response in milliseconds so that website  performances is not effected.Atleast i needed response as fast as possible.

Comment: $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("polyline"=>"37.779381,-122.418435,37.779381,-122.418435,37.779153,-122.418391...."));
$curl_exec =  curl_exec($ch);